# Asking for multiple Variables in one input Python

Tags: python, input

In the example below I am trying to print the three variables I put in. If I try to separate the different inputs with commas, it gives me this error message:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20,20,20'

If you need to know more, I'm happy to help.

```
A, B, C = int(input("how do I do this?"))
print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
```

Comment: can you share your code here so I can spot the error?

Comment: `a,b,c = map(int, input().split(','))`

Comment: I really like your answer @sahasrara62, should probably be the actual answer. But I guess it doesn't really matter as the question is closed now.

Comment: I can't his answer is too short to count as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
A, B, C = (int(value) for value in input("how do I do this?").split(','))
print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you enter in the input "1,2,3", it's converted to [1, 2, 3] (using the split method) then each variable is assigned to an element of the list.

```
a, b, c = map(int, input("how do I do this?").split(","))
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Comment: The type of a, b, c is not correct in this answer. The question is asking for ints, not strings.

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen corrected it, thanks for the comment

Comment: I really like this answer too. I use map too seldom.